# "keyCode" function gets slashed out on writing it in VS code

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, game-development

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPCBA.png) the fragment of the js code for your reference. At the place where I have written `e.keyCode`, the text `keyCode` gets slashed out and a yellow bulb appears alongside it.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    console.log("Key code is: ", e.keyCode)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keycode is deprecated and shouldn't be used. You should become familiar with the MDN documentation for most of your Javascript questions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by adding event listener in the beginning. Here's the fragment of code for your reference.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==32){
        hero = document.querySelector('.hero');
        hero.classList.add('animatehero');
        audiojump.play();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) instead.

Check it out at the MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

You can play with my code snippet and get info from console about event-codes(just press different buttons and see the result)

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  let str = "KeyboardEvent: key='" 
    + event.key + "' | code='" 
    + event.code + "'"; 
  console.log(str);
}, true);
```